# My script cannot import Authenticator from aws-amplify - does that mean it did not install correctly?

Tags: aws-amplify

I recently installed aws amplify using

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@latest
```

I am using the basic script verbatim from the aws-amplify site:

```js
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
//import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import '@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css';


import awsExports from '../../aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

I am receiving an error that
Module '"@aws-amplify/ui-react"' has no exported member 'Authenticator'.ts(2305)

I am using aws-amplify version 8.5. The backend is configured correctly. I am able to import "withAuthenticator". Does this mean it did not install correctly? I uninstalled and reinstalled it but still get the error. How can I import the Authenticator from the aws-amplify module?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using v1 of `@aws-amplify/ui-react`. Your example command installs the latest version of the CLI, but not the `@aws-amplify/ui-react` package. Please try updating to the latest version of `@aws-amplify/ui-react`:

```
npm install @aws-amplify/ui-react@latest
```

Also, you will want to change your CSS styles import to the line you've commented out:

```
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
```

See https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/getting-started/installation

Comment: That was it! I thought I used that command, but I believe permissions may have stopped it from installing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> Node.js follows the commonJS module system, and it require to include modules that exist in separate files and for that purpose it has methods like “require” and “ES6 import and export” are available in node.js.

So i used the require method, in my app.js file

```
const { withAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } = require("@aws-amplify/ui-react");
```

too in my index.js file i used the own import method for the Amplify function!

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify'; or just we can too use the require method
```

// const { Amplify } = require("aws-amplify");

Thanks aws.

Comment: sorry if my english isn't very well, salute from colombia.